# Nodejs application hosted on heroku failed to create products yet on localhost it does it fine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this nodejs app created to enable fellow students post ads of stuff they want to sell, i have hosted it on heroku but when a user logs in and tries to create an ad he is redirected to their dashboard (like its programmed to do) but without showing any ad they have created, even after refreshing. Meanwhile on mongodb their is also no ad object created. The app doesn't crash or stop working at all. I'm really a beginner a this but any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the handlebarsjs template for the form for data input

```
<header id="details-header">
        <h5><a href="/">Go back to Home</a></h5>
        <p></p>
    </header>
    <div class="registration-form">
        <form class="form custom__form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-icon">
                <span><i class="fa-light fa-money-check-pen"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p>Add image</p>
                <div class="custom__image-container">
                <label id="add-img-label" for="add-single-img">+</label>
                <input type="file" id="add-single-img" accept="image/jpeg" />
                </div>
                <input type="file" class="item form-control" id="image-input" name="profile-files" accept="image/jpeg" multiple />
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control item" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea type="text" id="body" name="body" class="form-control item" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter the product description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="category" id="category" class=" form-control item">
                        <option value="">Select a category :</option>
                        <option value="beds and mattresses">Beds &amp; mattresses</option>
                        <option value="chairs and tables">Chairs &amp; Tables</option>
                        <option value="laptops and phones">Laptops &amp; Phones</option>
                        <option value="appliances and electronics">Appliances &amp; electronics</option>
                        <option value="clothing">Clothing</option>
                        <option value="services and foods">Services &amp; Foods</option>
                        <option value="medical equipment">Medical Equipment</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control item" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price e.g 20000" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control item" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Location" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control item"  name="phone-number" id="phone-number" placeholder="Phone Number e.g 0754536336" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control item"  name="displayname" id="displayname" placeholder="Your name users will see" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Post Ad" class="btn btn-block create-account">
            </div>
        </form>
```

below is the form.js for functions running on the form

```
const title = document.getElementById('title')
const body = document.getElementById('body')
const price = document.getElementById('price')
const locationText = document.getElementById('location')
const phone = document.getElementById('phone-number')
const category = document.getElementById('category')
const displayname = document.getElementById('displayname')

const imgInputHelper = document.getElementById("add-single-img");
const imgInputHelperLabel = document.getElementById("add-img-label");
const imgContainer = document.querySelector(".custom__image-container");
const imgFiles = [];

const addImgHandler = () => {
const file = imgInputHelper.files[0];
if (!file) return;
// Generate img preview
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = () => {
const newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = reader.result;
    imgContainer.insertBefore(newImg, imgInputHelperLabel);
};
// Store img file
imgFiles.push(file);
// Reset image input
imgInputHelper.value = "";
    return;
};
imgInputHelper.addEventListener("change", addImgHandler);

const getImgFileList = (imgFiles) => {
const imgFilesHelper = new DataTransfer();
imgFiles.forEach((imgFile) => imgFilesHelper.items.add(imgFile));
return imgFilesHelper.files;
};

const customFormSubmitHandler = (ev) => {
ev.preventDefault();
const firstImgInput = document.getElementById("image-input");
firstImgInput.files = getImgFileList(imgFiles);
// submit form to server, etc
fileUpload(firstImgInput.files);
window.location.href='/dashboard'
};

document
.querySelector(".custom__form")
.addEventListener("submit", customFormSubmitHandler);

// Function that handles file upload using XHR
const fileUpload = (files) => {

// Create FormData instance
const fd = new FormData();

// Iterate over all selected files
Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
    fd.append('product-file', file);
});

fd.append('title', title.value)
fd.append('body', body.value)
fd.append('price', price.value)
fd.append('location', locationText.value)
fd.append('number', phone.value)
fd.append('category', category.value)
fd.append('displayname', displayname.value)

// Create XHR rquest
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Log HTTP response
xhr.onload = () => {
    // console.log(xhr.response);
    console.log('success')
};

// Send XHR reqeust
xhr.open('POST', `/products`);
xhr.send(fd);

};
```

Below is the nodejs route code for saving the data into the database

```
//@desc Process add form
//@route POST /products
router.post('/products', ensureAuthenticated, upload.array("product-file"), async (req, res) => { 
        
        // var locaFilePath = req.file.path;
        // var result = await uploadToCloudinary(locaFilePath);
        // console.log(result)
        // console.log(req.file)

        var imageUrlList = [];
  
        for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            var locaFilePath = req.files[i].path;
            var result = await uploadToCloudinary(locaFilePath);
            imageUrlList.push(result.url);
        }
            
        try {
            let product = new Product({
                title: req.body.title,
                body: req.body.body,
                image1: imageUrlList[0],
                image2: imageUrlList[1],
                image3: imageUrlList[2],
                price: req.body.price,
                category: req.body.category,
                phone_number : convertNumberToInternational(req.body.number.trim()),
                location: req.body.location,
                name: req.body.displayname,
                user: req.user.id,

            })
        await product.save()
        // req.body.user = req.user.id
        // await Product.create(req.body)
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.render('error/500')
    }
})
```

It's alot of lines but please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend from your code i can see you create new object,add it on your database with nodejs and then you redirect to another page(dashboard),which is correct.When you post something new ,your dashboard page should dynamically change and show new contents.Thats why you should use ejs in your project,to create dynamic pages,this way your dashboard page will show every new ad that will be posted.

Start from creating views directory and inside create dashboard.ejs file and inside show new ads (ads array) from users.Something like this

```
//add your title and anything else you want in your page
  <%  ads_array.forEach(function(ad){ %>

    <h1><%=ad.title%></h1>
    <p>
    <% }) %>
```

And in your nodejs post request,redirect user to dashboard.ejs file and push new ads to ads array

```
res.render("dashboard", {
      ads_array: ads
}
```

In a few words and as simple as i can tell it,you need to create dashboard.ejs file(./views/dashboard.ejs),this will be a dynamic page that will show ads posted from users,it's the way to have pages to change dynamic with every new post.

In nodejs file you make post request and redirect user in this page to see all ads.But you also need to create a new array,called ads,where you will push every new ad that will be created in post request.This information(ads array),will be send into dashboard.ejs file to show it in dashboard page.

You are trying to add dynamic content into a static page,thats why you have to use ejs template.
I hope this will help you see the errors,as for the heroku problems make sure you follow all steps from heroku documentation.

Comment: Thanks alot , I've been trying to avoid ejs because the tutorial I learnt from had handlebarsjs but with this I'll have to go with ejs.

Comment: No problem,i hope using ejs your project will work fine!